# PHP Explode Show Seperator

Tags: php, special-characters, explode

So I wrote the following code to show the words after the fourth full stop / period in a sentence.

```
$text = "this.is.the.message.seperated.with.full.stops.";
$limit = 4;

   $minText = explode(".", $text);

   for($i = $limit; $i < count($minText); $i++){
       echo $minText[$i];
   }
```

The algorithm is working and it is showing me the rest of the sentence after the fourth "." full stop / period.... My problem is that the output is not showing the full stops in the sentence therefore it is showing me just text without the proper punctuation "." .... Can someone please help me out on how to fix the code to display also the full stops / periods ??

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you want to see all the periods that exist between words or just the one at the end?

Comment: Can you show what exactly do you need to avoid some confusion? For example - do you need "seperated.with.full.stops." or "....seperated.with.full.stops." or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this...

```
    for($i = $limit; $i < count($minText); $i++){
       echo $minText[$i].".";
   }
```

notice the added period at the end of the echo command // .".";

Comment: This solved my problem... Worked as a charm @superkayrad ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "this.is.the.message.seperated.with.full.stops.";
$limit = 4;
$minText = explode(".", $text);
for($i = $limit; $i < count($minText); $i++){
    echo $minText[$i].".";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break it up on the periods between words, but keep the one at the end as actual punctuation, you may want to use `preg_replace()` to convert the periods to another character and then explode it.

```
$text = "this.is.the.message.seperated.with.full.stops.";
$limit = 4;

//replace periods if they are follwed by a alphanumeric character
$toSplit = preg_replace('/\.(?=\w)/', '#', $text);

   $minText = explode("#", $toSplit);

   for($i = $limit; $i < count($minText); $i++){
       echo $minText[$i] . "<br/>";
   }
```

Which Yields

```
seperated
with
full
stops.
```

Of course, if you just simply want to print all the full stops, then add them in after you `echo` the term.

```
echo $minText[$i] . ".";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting the input string and then iterating over it, you can find the nth position of the separator (.) in the string by using strpos() function by changing the offset parameter.

Then, it is just the matter of printing the sub-string from the position we just determined.

```
<?php

$text = "this.is.the.message.seperated.with.full.stops.";
$limit = 4;
$pos = 0;

//find the position of 4th occurrence of dot 
for($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
    $pos = strpos($text, '.', $pos) + 1;
}

print substr($text, $pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

If desired output is "seperated.with.full.stops.", then you can use:

```
<?php

$text = "this.is.the.message.seperated.with.full.stops.";
$limit = 4;

$minText = explode(".", $text);
$minText = array_slice($minText, $limit);

echo implode('.', $minText) . '.';
```